# How to pass the content of a macro to a command?

Tags: macros, expansion, tokcycle

For the development of a class file I am trying to perform some basic checking on strings (which can contain latex commands).
For this I use the **tokcycle** package.

When I pass a string directly everything works as expected.
For various reasons (we store arguments using **pgfkeys** and later retireve these values if they exist) I need to process the *content* of a macro.

How to pass the content of a macro to a command?
Or get **tokcycle** to work on the content of the macro without expending the macro since we want to detect macro's in the input string (such as "Test\test").

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tokcycle}

\newcommand\checkstring[1]{%
  \typeout{CHECKING -----------  #1}%
  \tokcycle{\typeout{CHARACTER: ##1}}%
           {\typeout{GROUP: ##1}}%
           {\typeout{MACRO: \string##1}}%
           {\typeout{SPACE: ##1}}%
           {#1}%
}

\newcommand\good[1]{%
  \checkstring{#1}%
}

\newcommand\problem[1]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \checkstring{\tmp}%
}

\begin{document}
\good{Test.}
\problem{Test.}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

```
CHECKING ----------- Test.
CHARACTER: T
CHARACTER: e
CHARACTER: s
CHARACTER: t
CHARACTER: .
CHECKING ----------- Test.
MACRO: \tmp
```

I would like to have the output identical in both cases.

Comment: `\expandafter\checkstring\expandafter{\tmp}`.

Comment: Great! That is a very clean solution: it also works when \tmp contains macros.

Comment: When it won't work properly is if the argument contains more than a single token, the first of which is a macro (e.g. `\expandafter\checkstring\expandafter{\today ABC}`).  See my posted answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can step over the expansion of a token by using `\expandafter`. You'll also need to step over the opening brace to get what you want, which is why you'd need `\expandafter\checkstring\expandafter{\tmp}`.

If all that you need is list the contents of the argument for debugging purposes, I suggest to use the build in `expl3`-function `\tl_analysis_log:n` instead of building your own version using the `tokcycle` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \checkstring \tl_analysis_log:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\good[1]{%
  \checkstring{#1}%
}

\newcommand\problem[1]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \expandafter\checkstring\expandafter{\tmp}%
}

\begin{document}
\good{Test.}
\problem{Test.}
\end{document}
```

Which will print the following to your log file:

```
The token list contains the tokens:
>  T (the letter T)
>  e (the letter e)
>  s (the letter s)
>  t (the letter t)
>  . (the character .)
The token list contains the tokens:
>  T (the letter T)
>  e (the letter e)
>  s (the letter s)
>  t (the letter t)
>  . (the character .)
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment rightfully suggested an approach employing `\expandafter`.  However, that approach cannot be used blindly, as it won't work properly if the argument contains more than a single token, the first of which is a macro (e.g. `\expandafter\checkstring\expandafter{\today ABC}`).

Here, the `\checkstring` macro will test whether the argument is a single token (e.g., a macro) and if so, expand it before processing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tokcycle}

\def\ckstringtest{\relax}
\def\checkstringaux{%
  \tokcycle{\typeout{CHARACTER: ##1}}%
           {\typeout{GROUP: ##1}}%
           {\typeout{MACRO: \string##1}}%
           {\typeout{SPACE: ##1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\checkstring[1]{%
  \typeout{CHECKING -----------  #1}%
%  
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\ckstringtest\@gobble#1\ckstringtest
    \expandafter\checkstringaux\expandafter{#1}%
  \else
    \checkstringaux{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\checkstring{Test.\today}

\def\tmp{Test.\today}
\checkstring{\tmp}

Done.
\end{document}
```

The contents of the log file include:

```
CHECKING ----------- Test.August 23, 2023
CHARACTER: T
CHARACTER: e
CHARACTER: s
CHARACTER: t
CHARACTER: .
MACRO: \today
CHECKING ----------- Test.August 23, 2023
CHARACTER: T
CHARACTER: e
CHARACTER: s
CHARACTER: t
CHARACTER: .
MACRO: \today
```